# Monetise website via Amazon affiliate? Or other means

Tags: seo, traffic, affiliate, monetize

I have an idea for an information based website that would potentially drive a large amount of traffic to a particular destination. Initially I wanted to drive traffic to the products own website but a colleague suggested potentially driving it to an Amazon page. Is it possible to earn some kind of affiliate revenue from this?

My original idea was to drive traffic to the companies own website - if the traffic was sufficient to then get in touch with them and take it from there.

Either way, I just want to include a button that takes them through to the website... whichever method I use.

I'm essentially generating extremely good leads I guess.

Just to give you a background - I've stumbled across an alternative use for a product, bought a domain and written the content that should get a high level of traffic... I'm just exploring ways to monetise it. I'm a web developer so was just using this website as a playground to try some things out at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

[Amazon has a an affiliate program](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/).   You [earn 4-10% of purchases](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/help/operating/advertisingfees) where your referred the buyer.

Amazon offers [several options for linking](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/join/landing/tools.html) to them such as:

- Product links (image, text, or both)
- Widgets
- Banners
- Mini Store

[Here is the link for applying](http://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/apply/main.html).

I've used Amazon links to monetize pages that are specifically about a product that is offered on Amazon.    For pages not about a product I've found that [Google AdSense](https://www.google.com/adsense/start/) monitizes my sites better.